# Quartic Equation have four real roots $x=\frac{1}{\alpha^3},\frac{1}{\alpha},\alpha,\alpha^3(\alpha>0)$

Tags: polynomials

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Quadratic Equation  $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+ax+1=0$  have four real roots
$x=\frac{1}{\alpha^3},\frac{1}{\alpha},\alpha,\alpha^3(\alpha>0)$ and $2a+b=14$.

Find $a,b=?(a,b\in\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Why don't you just expand out the product of the linear factors?

Comment: This is quartic and not quadratic. You could modify the title.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$0=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+ax+1=(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^3)\left(x-\frac1\alpha\right)\left(x-\frac1{\alpha^3}\right)$$

Now compare coefficients in both sides (Viete's Formulas), for example:

$$-a=\alpha+\alpha^3+\frac1\alpha+\frac1{\alpha^3}\;,\;\;b=\alpha^4+\frac1{\alpha^4}+\alpha^2+\frac1{\alpha^2}+2\;\ldots$$

Comment: have you found any elegant solution of the bi-quadratic equation in $\alpha+1/\alpha$? or any other way to find $a,b$ without solving the equation?

Comment: I've not even tried it. Hopefully the above will help, but it could be it won't.

Comment: Solving for the condition 2a+b=14 leads to a quite unpleasant equation for the OP. The resulting equation reduces to the product of a linear term squared (one root), multiplied by a quadratic term (two distinct roots) , multiplied by a quartic term; this last one has no real root. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Shall we let the OP work his way into *his* problem, with these and those hints? Maybe he'll succeed, or else he'll write back.

Comment: @DonAntonio. I totally agree with you. What I was concern in my comment is this extra condition which makes the problem quite difficult (I suppose) except if there is a smart transform in terms of some combination of alpha. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

lab has a point. if we write $x=\alpha +\frac1{\alpha}$
then we get
$$
-ax + b = x^2+2
$$
or
$$
x= \frac12 \left((-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4(2-b)}\right) 
$$
but for a 'nice' problem the $2a+b=14$ should simplify the surd, and it doesn't quite seem to. maybe my arithmetic is wrong, or maybe i'm just a hopeless optimist with a penchant for erroneous oversimplification. (well i know that, actually)